# How to distinguish the attribute & complement in a sentence?

Tags: complements

As an example:

> In some cultures, people regard men as breadwinners.

my textbook says: ''as breadwinners'' is the complement to ''regard'', but I think it is the attribute to ''men''. Which one is correct?

Also, can complements be used to describe verbs or other words? I only know they can be used to describe the subject and the object in a sentence.

Comment: Your textbook is right. "Breadwinners" is a predicative complement of "regard"; it only refers to "men". Complements can take many forms AdjPs, NPs, clauses etc. and be dependents of most word categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textbook is right. "Breadwinners" is a predicative complement of "regard"; it only refers to "men". Complements can take many forms AdjPs, NPs, clauses etc. and be dependents of most word categories.